# Custom policy with custom user attribute missing from JWT

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Our solution require a custom user attribute to be available for Graph API post/get operations and to be exposed with claims in the JWT for user user-in.

I have configured a custom policy with for Local Account.

The template files were downloaded from  and the only changes made is to add a new custom user attribute that is available for Azure AD read/write, persistent storage, claims output.

I added the policy files to a public repo here:
https://github.com/frode/azure-ad-b2c/tree/master/LocalAccountSignIn

The extension_tenantId attribute becomes available for Graph API operations, setting value and retrieving it works fine, however the attribute is never exposed in the JWTs claims section as we intended.

Can User flows and custom polices be used together or is that the problem that we have defined a user flow with the same name as the custom policy?

/Frode

Comment: Hi Frode. How did you create the custom attribute? Through the **Azure AD B2C > User attributes** blade?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett Yes. But i found the error in our config now. It was missing the app registration for "IdentityExperienceFramework".

Answer (score 0):

Was able to spot the issue in our configuration today.

src/Policies/LocalAccount/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml was missing the IdentityExperienceFramework app registration & GUID value.

Regards
Frode